# How to name multiple selects for form submit

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, submit

How do I name my selects inside my form when i have multiple select where multiple is set to true.

Here's an exemple:

```
<form action="/product/create" method="post">   
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[name]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="product[taxes]" multiple>
                <option value="1">Tax A</option>
                <option value="2">Tax B</option>
                <option value="3">Tax C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[price]">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[name]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="product[taxes]" multiple>
                <option value="1">Tax A</option>
                <option value="2">Tax B</option>
                <option value="3">Tax C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[price]">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[name]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="product[taxes]" multiple>
                <option value="1">Tax A</option>
                <option value="2">Tax B</option>
                <option value="3">Tax C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="product[price]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now if I select multiple taxes for each products. How do I know which taxes are selected for each lines since all the selected items will be merged into one array.

Here's the body of the post I would get:

```
{
    'product[name]': [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ],
    'product[taxes]': [ '1', '2', '1', '3', '2' ],
    'product[price]': [ '1', '2', '3' ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a multiple select can send *0–n* results, there is no way to distinguish between multiple controls with the same name based on the position of the values in the data.

You need to add some identifying token to either the name or all of the values.

```
name="rowId-product[name]"
```

… would probably be easiest. (Where rowId is an identifier for the row that is prepended to the name of every control in it).

Comment: So that implies that i have to test that each properties exists? Like does 1-product exists? does 2-product exists? etc...

Comment: It really depends on how your form data parser works, but probably something like `var n = 0; while ( (n++ + "-product") in myFormData ) { ... }`